# Keil assembly template for an embedded device

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, keil, nucleo

I'm using a [NUCLEO-L053R8](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l053r8.html) board which uses the [STM32L053R8T](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l053r8.html) microcontroller and I'm trying to run a sample assembly program like this one:

[image]

If I want to run the code in Keil, in debug mode to watch in hardware how the registers are affected, is see that startup directives need to be declared similar to these:

[image]

My question is, can Keil provide this startup template file? If negative, how can I build one or obtain a generic so the code can compile and be downloaded to the target nucleo board?